# LaTeX3: Defining key to set boolean variable

Tags: conditionals, expl3, latex3, documentation

I want to define a key, which, if set, sets a boolean variable to **false**.

The documentation is not clear on that point. It states (source3.pdf, sect. 87, p. 134):

> Defines `<key>` to set `<bool>` to `<value>`
>   (which must be either `true` or `false`).

However, I cannot see where to put the `false` value in the key definition. `<value>` is not present in the synopsis. It seems that the default behaviour is to set `<bool>` to `true`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `.bool_set:N` key property is intended to work as

```
\keys_define:nn { module }
  {
    key-name .bool_set:N = \l_my_bool
  }
```

which will be used as `key-name = true` or `key-name = false`. If you want to have the key name alone to be equivalent to setting `false`, you need a default:

```
\keys_define:nn { module }
  {
    key-name .bool_set:N = \l_my_bool ,
    key-name .default:n  = false
  }
```

However, I'd probably use a raw `.code:n` approach, as this seems to be 'backward' compared to what I'd expect

```
\bool_new:N \l_my_bool
\keys_define:nn { module } 
  {
    key-name .code:n = { \bool_set_false:N \l_my_bool } 
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. So, if I understand correctly, a `key-name` defined as `.bool_set:N` always requires a value and `key-name` alone raises an error? Is there no implicit `.default:n = true`?

Comment: @Alexander: It should set the default as `true`.